# In Django how to get this pandas dataframe to a template?

Tags: python, django, pandas

django newbie question:

Documentation with django and pandas focuses on models. I need to understand better how to trace the model, view and template where pandas is involved.

Here is an application problem:
I am trying to display mobile telephone allowances in an app.

For example, each mobile connection has a mandatory tariff and also four optional, value added services ('VAS'). Tariffs cannot be VAS, but you could have the same VAS four times to boost your allowances.

There is a single table 'Tariff' for managing the details of all tariffs and VAS.

For each call line identifier (mobile phone connection), we need to read the call minutes, data megabytes and text count allowances that sum from the associated tariff and four VAS columns.

```
# models.py

class Tariff(models.Model): 
                tariff_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, db_index=True)
                minutes = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
                texts = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
                data = models.FloatField(null=True, default=0)
                is_tariff_not_VAS = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class CallLineIdentifiers(models.Model):
        mobile_tel_number = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)
        tariff = models.ForeignKey(Tariff, related_name = 'tariffName' )
        vas_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default=0,)
        vas_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default=0,)
        vas_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default=0,)
        vas_4 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default=0,)
```

So far, so good. I can render an html page displaying allowances for a mobile based on just the main Tariff. 
If I want to include the VAS allowances things are more tricky. You can't just have foreign keys for each VAS back to the Tariff table.

But perhaps, **is there a django model re-specification that solves the problem?**

I've used Pandas before, for this problem - BUT outside of django.

This worked in pandas where I joined a table for call line identifiers with a copy of each tariff and VAS something like:

```
import pandas as pd

# df = a dataframe of call line identifiers, containing telephone number
# and the names of any 'Tariff', 'VAS ONE', 'VAS TWO', 'VAS THREE','VAS FOUR'
# that are assigned to that mobile.

# tandv = dataframe of tariff and vas with attributes, where
# 'Tariff' is unique primary key and the name of each tariff or VAS.



tariff_allowance = pd.merge(df, tandv, on 'Tariff')
v1_allowance = pd.merge(df, tandv, left_on = 'VAS ONE', right_on = 'Tariff')
v2_allowance = pd.merge(df, tandv, left_on = 'VAS TWO', right_on = 'Tariff')
v3_allowance = pd.merge(df, tandv, left_on = 'VAS THREE', right_on = 'Tariff')
v4_allowance = pd.merge(df, tandv, left_on = 'VAS FOUR', right_on = 'Tariff')

allow = tariff_allowance.merge(v1_allowance,on="cli")
            .merge(v2_allowance,on="cli")    
            .merge(v3_allowance,on="cli")
            .merge(v4_allowance,on="cli")  

# then, sum calls, data, texts attributes.
# keep only the necessary columns. 
# gives us an dataframe: "CLIs_with_allowances"
```

**What should my pandas block look like in django models?**

**How do I get from the resulting dataframe, "CLIs_with_allowances" to an html page?**

Thank you.